# Custom Gradle Publishing Plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins, publish, nexus

I am trying to create a plugin that captures some of the custom publishing that we do across multiple applications.

Here is the custom plugin:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication
import org.gradle.api.publish.maven.plugins.MavenPublishPlugin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip

class NexusDeployPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.tasks.create('zipManifests', Zip) {
            baseName project.name
            from 'manifests'
        }


        project.tasks.withType(MavenPublishPlugin) {
            project.plugins.apply(MavenBasePublishPlugin)

            dependsOn project.assemble

            project.publishing {
                publications {
                    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                        artifactId project.name
                        from components.java

                        artifact zipManifests {
                            artifactId project.name
                            classifier 'manifests'
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            project.repositories {
                maven {
                    url "http://myrepo/content/repositories/fakeLocation/"
                    credentials {
                        username 'username'
                        password 'password'
                    }
                    authentication {
                        basic(BasicAuthentication)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The `build.gradle` for the project that needs this just has:

```
apply plugin: NexusDeployPlugin
```

Everything compiles, but when I do a `./gradlew tasks`, the publish task doesn't show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: The line `project.tasks.withType(MavenPublishPlugin)` looks weird to me. You search for tasks with a plugin type as class. I'm pretty sure you'll never find such a task.

Comment: @lu.koerfer i am trying to *add* a publish task .... it sounds like you're saying this is not the way to do it...

Comment: You call `withType` on the `TaskContainer`, which should return a `TaskCollection` containing all the tasks with the specified type (and execute the following closure on them). But, since there will never be a task of the type, the closure will never be executed.

Comment: makes sense ... so any suggestions on how to create this correctly?